# How to link against a static library?

Tags: static-libraries, zig

I've a compiled static library, but don't have the code of it. I know the library embeds lots of files on compilation and looks something like this:

```
//files.zig
const std = @import("std");
pub const file_paths = [_][]const u8{
    "www/x/in.txt",
    "www/emd.txt",
    "www/index.html",
    "www/e2.txt",
};

const EmbeddedFile = struct {
    path: []const u8,
    content: []const u8,
};

pub const embedded_files = blk: {
    var fs: [file_paths.len]EmbeddedFile = undefined;
    for (file_paths) |file_path, i| {
        const embedded_file = EmbeddedFile{
            .path = file_path,
            .content = @embedFile(file_path),
        };
        fs[i] = embedded_file;
    }
    break :blk fs;
};
```

How can I use the library in my app? For example, how can I display the content of the file `www/index.html` that is embeded in this library, from my app code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Linking

If you want to use internals of a static library, you have to link against it firstly.
You can do it by using Zig build system or manually.

### Build System

For the first option you have to edit `build.zig` file in the root of your project by adding `addObjectFile("path")` to your executable object.

Here is the build file for `zig v0.10.1` which is automatically generated by `zig init-exe` command with `exe.addObjectFile` function call added

```
const std = @import("std");

pub fn build(b: *std.build.Builder) void {
    const mode = b.standardReleaseOptions();

    const exe = b.addExecutable("test_exe", "src/main.zig");
    exe.setTarget(target);
    exe.setBuildMode(mode);
    exe.install();

    exe.addObjectFile("path/to/file.a(or .lib if on Windows)"); // linking the executable against a "file.a" static library.

    const run_cmd = exe.run();
    run_cmd.step.dependOn(b.getInstallStep());
    if (b.args) |args| {
        run_cmd.addArgs(args);
    }

    const run_step = b.step("run", "Run the app");
    run_step.dependOn(&run_cmd.step);

    const exe_tests = b.addTest("src/main.zig");
    exe_tests.setTarget(target);
    exe_tests.setBuildMode(mode);

    const test_step = b.step("test", "Run unit tests");
    test_step.dependOn(&exe_tests.step);
}
```

### Manual linking

To link the library with only using Zig compiler you just need to add it's path into the list of targets like this:

```
zig build-exe src/main.zig path/to/the/lib.a
```

## Usage

To use exported functions/variables you have to declare them with the `extern` keyword. If you want to import something that uses non-primitive type, you should define it yourself.

> Usually, library developers provide header(for C) or package(for Zig) files if they want to distribute their library as a static or shared archive. These files contain all exported functions, variables, types, because a common user of a big library don't know anything about what is exported without them.

```
const std = @import("std");

const EmbeddedFile = struct {
    path: [*:0]const u8,
    content: [*:0]const u8,
};

// Notice the extern keyword. 
// It tells the compiler embedded_files is taken from a shared or static library.
extern const embedded_files: [4]EmbeddedFile;

pub fn main() !void {
    for (embedded_files) |file| {
        std.debug.print("file:\t\t{s}\n", .{file.path});
        std.debug.print("content:\t{s}\n", .{file.content});
    }
}
```

Output:

```
file:       www/x/in.txt
content:    text
file:       www/emd.txt
content:    text
file:       www/index.html
content:    text
file:       www/e2.txt
content:    text
```

#### Note

The code you provided can't represent the actual internals of the library, because:

- Nothing is exported here
- Slices can not be exported

So I assumed the library looks like this:

```
const std = @import("std");

const file_paths = [_][]const u8{
    "www/x/in.txt",
    "www/emd.txt",
    "www/index.html",
    "www/e2.txt",
};

const EmbeddedFile = extern struct {
    path: [*:0]const u8,
    content: [*:0]const u8,
};

export const embedded_files = blk: {
    var fs: [file_paths.len]EmbeddedFile = undefined;
    for (file_paths) |file_path, i| {
        const embedded_file = EmbeddedFile{
            .path = file_path[0.. :0],
            .content = @embedFile(file_path)[0.. :0],
        };
        fs[i] = embedded_file;
    }
    break :blk fs;
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked perfectly with copiling the packaged as static `const lib = b.addSharedLibrary("Zig", "src/main.zig");` but failed when I defind it as shared `const lib = b.addSharedLibrary("Zig", "src/main.zig", .unversioned);` though I changed the file extension from `.a` to `.so` at `exe.addObjectFile("../embed-lib/zig-out/lib/libZig.so");`, I got compilation error `Segmentation fault at address 0x0` at `for (embedded_files)`

Comment: @HasanAYousef It is probably a bug. Try to use 0.11 version.

Comment: It woked by fixeng the target at both `build.zig` for the lib and for the exe as `const target = std.zig.CrossTarget{ .os_tag = .windows, .cpu_arch = .x86_64 };` thanks again.